# Django filtering many to many as separate records

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, orm

I have such models:

```
class Something(Model):
    """ fields here """

class SomethingHelper(Model):
    name = TextField()
    something = models.ManyToManyField(Something, default=None)
```

So what I need to do is: if SomethingHelper has many related objects in something field, get all of them as separate queryset objects, for example:

```
{id=0, name="first_one", something=something1},
{id=0, name="first_one", something=something2},
{id=0, name="first_one", something=something3}
```

not

```
{id=0, name="first_one", something=QuerySet([something1, something2, something3])}
```

as is by standard filtering.

Is this possible in Django ? Can you please suggest something ? Thanks

Comment: values() provide you such results
something.values()

Comment: `something_instance.somethinghelper_set.all().values_list('id','name','somthing')`